# Regex for parsing multiple conditions for groups

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I am trying to split string in 3 different parts with regex.

I can only get function parameters from string but i also want to other parts of the string

```
const regex = /(\(.*?\))+/g;
const sampleString = 'collection.products(take:12|skip:16)';
const result = sampleString.match(regex)
```

It gives me `(take:12|skip:16)`

But i also want to get `collection` and `products`

Expected result in match

1. `collection`
2. `products`
3. `take:12|skip:16`

Comment: If your string is always like that, use [`sampleString.match(/[^)(.]+/g)`](https://jsfiddle.net/902x56kg/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, we can alter two expressions together:

```
(\w+)|\((.+?)\)
```

which group #1 would capture our desired words `(\w+)` and group #2 would capture the desired output in the brackets.

```js
const regex = /(\w+)|\((.+?)\)/gm;
const str = `collection.products(take:12|skip:16)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AOSXpx/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on `.` and `(\(.*?\))+` and then use reduce to get values in desired format

```js
const sampleString = 'collection.products(take:12|skip:16)';
const result = sampleString.split(/\.|(\(.*?\))+/).reduce((op,inp) => {
  if(inp){
    inp = inp.replace(/[)(]+/g,'')
    op.push(inp)
  }
  return op
},[])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This splits on what you want.

```js
const sampleString = 'collection.products(take:12|skip:16)';
const result = sampleString.split(/[.()]*([^.()]+)[.()]*/).filter(function (el) {return el != "";});

console.log(result)
```